# How to make a new instance of an object that doesn't overwrite the existing one?

Tags: java, instance

So, I've got some homework to do and I made a simple user input application that at the end outputs (I want that I do that) all inputs that were typed. The problem is I don't know how to make it that it doesn't overwrite the existing object but that it makes a new one.

I presume that I can make an array or something like that and it should resolve the problem, but it doesn't resolve my question, so I came here for help.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String next ="y";
        int studentNum = 1;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("Do you want to add a student? y/n");
            if(scanner.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                System.exit(0);

                for(int i = 0;i<studentNum;i++){

                Student student = new Student();
                System.out.println("ID: ");
                student.setId(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.println(("Ime: "));
                student.setName(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Prezime: ");
                student.setSurname(scanner.nextLine());

           System.out.println("Do you want to add another student? y/n");
           if(scanner.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
               studentNum+=1;
           else
               for(i =0;i<studentNum;i++)
               System.out.println(student.toString());


        }

    }
```

And the Student Class

```
public class Student {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("ID: %s \n%s %s\nAverage grade %.2f\n____________________\n",
                id, surname, name, averageGrade() );
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // pretpostavljamo da je predani objekt iz klase Student
        Student otherStudent = (Student) obj;
        return id.equals(otherStudent.id);
    }



    final int ARR_SIZE = 60;

     private String id;
     private String name;
     private String surname;
     private int noOfGrades;
     private CourseGrade[] grades;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String newId) {
        id = newId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String newSurname) {
        surname = newSurname;
    }
```

If I want to add another student it overwrites the existing one, which I expected, but I don't know how to make it that it makes a new instance.

Comment: You code *does* make a new `Student` instance each time. Do you mean how do you *store* the old student? If so, you would use a collection, `Set<Student>` or `List<Student>`.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by `does not overwrite` especially why array or list does not work for that definition of `overwrite`?

Comment: Hint: you have a constant named `ARR_SIZE`. Maybe make use of it.

Comment: IMO, this question should not have been approved.  It is unclear what is being asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example code of how to use a List to store several students:

```
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;        
    ..
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Student s = new Student();
    s.setName("Joe");
    students.add(s);

    Student t = new Student();
    t.setName("Jack");
    students.add(t);

    for(Student student : students) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
```

With this information, you should be able to finish your work.